# How to hide UIAlertView when receiving Push Notification in iOS

Tags: ios, hide, uialertview

In my iOS Application, I want to hide `UIAlertView` when receiving **push notification** in `didreceiveRemotenotification` method.
 Whole page of app delegate I am not writting code for show **UIAlertView**. Then why does it display automatically?

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
 [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; 
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) { self.noti_json=[userInfo objectForKey:@"msg"]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"] object:self];
 } }
```

Thanks in Advance.

***Edit*** (Adding code for my `didReceiveRemoteNotification:`):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{ 
   [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; 
   if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
   { 
      self.noti_json=[userInfo objectForKey:@"msg"];   
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"] object:self]; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: post your didreceiveRemotenotification method implementation

Comment: - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
   self.noti_json=[userInfo objectForKey:@"msg"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"] object:self];
  }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];`

and show your own alert only if the type is not the one you wanna avoid.

UserInfo must have some identifier or type of notification so that you can handle type specific notifications accordingly.

[Handle Push](https://www.parse.com/questions/pfpush-handlepush)

**Edit**

Or Simply use below line

```
if(![[userInfo objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"typeName"]){
 [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving alerts for Push Notifications it can be due to having the Alerts enabled in settings for your app.

Comment: if  notification disable from application setting then , i am not able to any notification related to my application.
i want to receive notification without displaying UIAlertview

Comment: my code is :
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
   self.noti_json=[userInfo objectForKey:@"msg"];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:[userInfo objectForKey:@"title"] object:self];
  }
  }